# Polynomial basis representation of elements of a finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Confusing text:

[image]

I thought different elements are represented by different coefficients, $g_i$. Can someone explain me the second part of the text, one about roots of the polynomial.

Comment: The $g_i$ are the coef's of the irred poly. It is the $\,a_i\,$ that are the coef's of of $\,\alpha\,$ (these coeffs depend on $\,\alpha)\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque So these are two different representations? What's the point of using roots?

Comment: Where do you see "two different representations"?

Comment: @BillDubuque One representation using F(x) and it's coefficients, other using the root of F(x) and it's coefficients.

Comment: What is the source of your quote? More context is needed. Do you know any ring theory, e.g. do you know the isomorphism $\, K[x]/(F(x))\cong K[\alpha]?\ $ It seems you may be confusing the two based on some informal remarks in the text (which are missing above).

Comment: @BillDubuque I do know some ring theory, not this isomorphism. I will start from the answer below, to see what's what. Any recommendations on what to search for?

Comment: It's hard to say not knowing anything about your mathematical knowledge or the level of the text you are using, etc. Is it from a course if discrete math, or crypography?  if you can link to the text you will get much better answers.

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm just piecing things together from different sources. Making a presentation for a course which didn't explain too much math. From ring theory I know chapter 1 from [here](http://www.unalmed.edu.co/~mmtoro/doc/hartleyhawkes.pdf)  Also, I know what homomorphism and kernel are.

Comment: Ok, so you haven't yet reached the chapter on quotient rings, The above can be explained in simpler congruence language. Do you think that might help you?  Are you familiar with integer congruences or modular arithmetic, e.g. $\ {\rm mod}\ 10\!:\,\ 9^{2N}\equiv (-1)^{2N}\equiv 1\ ?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque "The field of integers modulo p" from [here](http://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/23/elliptic-curve-cryptography-finite-fields-and-discrete-logarithms/#disqus_thread) is known to me. Also, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general representation of $\Bbb F_{p^m}$ is $\Bbb F _p [X] / (F)$ where $F$ is *any* *irreducible* polynomial in $\Bbb F_p [X]$ of degree $m$ (it turns out that all these polynomials lead to isomorphic quotient rings).

Now, since $F$ is irreducible, in particular it cannot have roots in $F_p$. Let $\alpha$ be any root of $F$ in the algebraic closure $\overline {\Bbb F_p}$ of $\Bbb F_p$. Consider the ring morphism $i : \Bbb F _p [X] \to \Bbb F _p (\alpha)$ given by $i(f) = f(\alpha)$ (where one naturally views $f \in \Bbb F _p [X]$ as an element of $\Bbb F _p (\alpha) [X]$).

Let us prove that $i$ is surjective. If $\beta \in \Bbb F_p (\alpha) = \Bbb F_p [\alpha]$ (the last equality being true because $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\Bbb F_p$), then $\beta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \alpha + \dots + \beta_m \alpha^m$ with $\beta_i \in \Bbb F_p \ \forall i$. Then, if $f = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \dots + \beta_m X^m \in \Bbb F_p [x]$, it follows that $i(f) = \beta$, so $i$ is indeed surjective.

Concerning the kernel, notice that $i(f) = 0 \iff f(\alpha) = 0 \iff F \mid f$, so $\ker i \simeq (F)$.

By the fundamental isomorphism theorem, then, you get that $\Bbb F _p [X] / (F) \simeq \Bbb F_p (\alpha)$ and since we already knew that $\Bbb F_{p^m} \simeq \Bbb F _p [X] / (F)$, it follows that $\Bbb F_p (\alpha) = \Bbb F_p [\alpha]$ is another representation of $\Bbb F_{p^m}$.

Comment: $F_p[X]$ represents all polynomials with base $F_p$. Right?

Comment: @Desperado: All polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$.